# Updating linux to the next Kernel

Tags: linux, kernel

I have just downloaded CentOS 5.3.

The kernel version is 2.6.18.xx However, when I updated the kernel version has not changed. Still 2.6.18. Unless something went wrong with the updates.

The most up to date kernel is 2.6.31.xx I was thinking shouldn't it update to this new kernel?

On my Fedora 12 I have 2.6.31. I know that Fedora is bleeding edge technology. However, I thought the kernel of 2.6.18 would have been updated as least a little. It seems to be very old.

Comment: Actually, 2.6.31 is considered stable and is run on many mainstream distros, notably Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distributions like CentOS are more enterprise orientated, so don't expect to end up on the most recent kernel. CentOS is essentially a recompiled Red Hat Enterprise Linux, and RHEL sticks with a known-good kernel for quite a while. They do, however, back-port security fixes into their kernel as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

What update method are you using? If you're building from source, some additional tweaking is involved. If you want to avoid the tweaking, you can simply run `yum update kernel`.

Also note that a reboot is required to run the new kernel.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained better, I wasn't building from source. I did: yum upgrade. However, I think there was a break in my Internet so it didn't get installed. However, am I right that will be update to the latest kernel which is 2.6.31?

Comment: It should. To confirm you can run `yum list updates 'kernel*'` to see available kernel upgrades.

Comment: Hello, I have just checked the kernel version uname -a and I can confirm that it is still 2.6.18. No change. I have done yum update kernel. And it saids "not packages marked for update." When I run yum list updates 'kernel*'. It gives an error 'Error: No matching Packages to list'. Thanks.

Comment: If there is no available update you may be running the latest. Refer to developmentalinsanity's answer for more info.

Answer (score 2):

I quasi-regularly update my kernel at home, with CentOS repositories. The latest available kernel is 2.6.18-164.11.1.el5.centos.plus as of this writing for CentOS.

If you want to get [2.6.32](http://linux.slashdot.org/story/09/12/03/1415206/Linux-Kernel-2632-Released), then you'll have to compile from source, as other posters have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You might try CentOS 5.4.  In general, once a new version of a distro is released, the old ones only get security fixes.